# How to setup treesitter in vim script?

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua, plugin-treesitter

I have my entire nvim setup written in vim script at ~/.config/nvim/init.vim, but tresitter on it's GitHub says

```
require'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
  -- A list of parser names, or "all" (the five listed parsers should always be installed)
  ensure_installed = { "c", "lua", "vim", "vimdoc", "query" },

  -- Install parsers synchronously (only applied to `ensure_installed`)
  sync_install = false,

  -- Automatically install missing parsers when entering buffer
  -- Recommendation: set to false if you don't have `tree-sitter` CLI installed locally
  auto_install = true,

  -- List of parsers to ignore installing (for "all")
  ignore_install = { "javascript" },

  ---- If you need to change the installation directory of the parsers (see -> Advanced Setup)
  -- parser_install_dir = "/some/path/to/store/parsers", -- Remember to run vim.opt.runtimepath:append("/some/path/to/store/parsers")!

  highlight = {
    enable = true,

    -- NOTE: these are the names of the parsers and not the filetype. (for example if you want to
    -- disable highlighting for the `tex` filetype, you need to include `latex` in this list as this is
    -- the name of the parser)
    -- list of language that will be disabled
    disable = { "c", "rust" },
    -- Or use a function for more flexibility, e.g. to disable slow treesitter highlight for large files
    disable = function(lang, buf)
        local max_filesize = 100 * 1024 -- 100 KB
        local ok, stats = pcall(vim.loop.fs_stat, vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(buf))
        if ok and stats and stats.size > max_filesize then
            return true
        end
    end,

    -- Setting this to true will run `:h syntax` and tree-sitter at the same time.
    -- Set this to `true` if you depend on 'syntax' being enabled (like for indentation).
    -- Using this option may slow down your editor, and you may see some duplicate highlights.
    -- Instead of true it can also be a list of languages
    additional_vim_regex_highlighting = false,
  },
}
```

How and where do I put it in init.vim so I can tweak tresitter from text file (.vim or .lua)? I use vundle plugin manager.

Comment: @Friedrich thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard" way is to:

- Create a `treesitter.lua` file in `~/.config/nvim/lua/config`
- Copy the GitHub proposition in that file
- Add the following line in `init.vim`:

```
lua require('config/treesitter')
```

Comment: I did everything as you said and got ```Error detected while processing /Users/vladyslav/dotfiles/nvim/init.vim:
line  101:
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: module 'config/treesitter' not found:
        no field package.preload['config/treesitter']
        no file './config/treesitter.lua'  < I skipped some output to fit in comment>  
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue```

Comment: The ~/.config/nvim is  a link to ~/dotfiles/nvim

Comment: You can find my init files and error photo at https://github.com/Dolfost/dotfiles/tree/lua/test/nvim

Comment: Is the `treesitter.lua` file in `~/.config/nvim/lua/config` or for you in `~/dotfiles/nvim/lua/config`? From the repository I have the impression that it is in `~/dotfiles/nvim/lua`. Which is actually my mistake because I wrote that in the first version of my answer :-/ sorry for that.

Comment: Yes, it is in `~/dotfiles/nvim/lua`. No problems buddy.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-).